# Spark MLib Word2Vec Error: The vocabulary size should be > 0

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, apache-spark-mllib, word2vec

I am trying to implement word vectorization using Spark's MLLib. I am following the example given [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-feature-extraction.html#example).

I have bunch of sentences which I want to give as input to train the model. But am not sure if this model takes sentences or just takes all the words as a sequence of string.

My input is as below:

```
scala> v.take(5)
res31: Array[Seq[String]] = Array(List([WrappedArray(0_42)]), List([WrappedArray(big, baller, shoe, ?)]), List([WrappedArray(since, eliud, win, ,, quick, fact, from, runner, from, country, kalenjins, !, write, ., happy, quick, fact, kalenjins, location, :, kenya, (, kenya's, western, highland, rift, valley, ), population, :, 4, ., 9, million, ;, compose, 11, subtribes, language, :, kalenjin, ;, swahili, ;, english, church, :, christianity, ~, africa, inland, church, [, aic, ],, church, province, kenya, [, cpk, ],, roman, catholic, church, ;, islam, translation, :, kalenjin, translate, ", tell, ", formation, :, wwii, ,, gikuyu, tribal, member, wish, separate, create, identity, ., later, ,, student, attend, alliance, high, school, (, first, british, public, school, kenya, ), form, ...
```

But when I try to train my word2vec model on this input it does not work.

```
scala> val word2vec = new Word2Vec()
word2vec: org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.Word2Vec = org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.Word2Vec@51567040

scala> val model = word2vec.fit(v)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The vocabulary size should be > 0. You may need to check the setting of minCount, which could be large enough to remove all your words in sentences.
```

Does `Word2Vec` not take sentences as input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your input is correct. However, `Word2Vec` will automatically remove words that do not occur a minimum number of times in the vocabulary (all sentences combined). By default this value is 5. In your case, it is highly likely that no word occurs 5 or more times in the data you use.

To change the minimum required word occurrences use `setMinCount()`, for example a min count of 2:

```
val word2vec = new Word2Vec().setMinCount(2)
```

Comment: It works when I set the mincount to be 2. Anways I was getting that error when I was running on just sample input.But when I trained the model on full input,It finished running without throwing any error even by leavingthe min count to default(5)

Comment: @vish: Yes, since there are a lot more words in the full input compared to the sample one it would work. Depending on which words you want in the he result you can adjust the min count to be higher or lower.