# Setting minDF and vocabularysize of CountVectorizerModel in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am writing a spark Scala code using CountVectorizerModel and MinHashLSH library  for finding Jaccard similarity in two sets of string in a datafarme. Before feeding it to the MinHashLSH, it should be converted into vectors. For that I  am using CountVectorizerModel.

The problem is that I am randomly setting the values like setVocabSize() and setMinDF() as shown below in the code. I am getting an error `vocabulary size should be > 0. Lower minDF as necessary spark error`.

The snippet of dataframe dfB look like below and its size changes according to the input.

```
 +------------+-----------------+
|         id1|          values1|
+------------+-----------------+
|         USA|  [Stat]|
|     Germany|[Country]|
| Clever_Hans|  [Horse]|
|       China|[Country]|
|       Japan|[Country]|
|     Halidae| [Family]|
|Real_Delight|  [Horse]|
|Bago_(horse)|  [Horse]|

val dfB = hashtoseq1.toDF("id1", "values1")

val cvModel1: CountVectorizerModel = new CountVectorizer()
  .setInputCol("values1")
  .setOutputCol("features1")
  .setVocabSize(100000)
  .setMinDF(1)
  .fit(dfB)

val kt1 = cvModel1.transform(dfB)
//  kt.show
val mh1 = new MinHashLSH()
  .setNumHashTables(5)
  .setInputCol("features1")
  .setOutputCol("hashes1")

val model1 = mh1.fit(kt1)

val dffilter1 = model1.approxSimilarityJoin(kt1, kt1, 0.4)
```

The above line code works for the file size less than 4GB. For 17 GB file, its throwing an error. I went through the spark document and folowing links, but did not help me.

[Spark MLib Word2Vec Error: The vocabulary size should be > 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48086226/spark-mlib-word2vec-error-the-vocabulary-size-should-be-0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your corpus contains less than 100000 terms. Usually your document contains - depending on the size of your documents - millions of terms. The algorithm then limits that space to your `vocabSize` eliminating highly unique values.

For this to work you need to decrease your `vocabSize <= total number terms in your corpus = 4`.